# Android Studio: Kanji, katakana and hiragana in search box are not shown

Tags: android-studio

I updated Android Studio to the Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2 and before Android Studio 4.1.1 was handling Japanese text in the search box. However, maybe there is a way to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the Android Studio's Preferences(If you are using MacOS). Then go to the Appearance& Behavior => Appearance => check [use custom font] and select [JetBrains Mono]. Finally, click [OK].
Please see the picture here, if you aren't clear

[image: 1]